# Querying unique WooCommerce sales by user id if product belongs to a specific category

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm looking for a performant way to construct a query for Woocommerce sales by unique users if a product is in a specific category. The virtual products technically have unlimited stock but are limited to the first 100 people purchasing. I'm tracking this currently by a specific product category with some metadata attached.

My current approach is to hook into the woocommerce_payment_complete action, query the order items, grab their category and associated meta value for purchase limit, then compare that against the number of orders that have currently been placed for that category, if we find a match I'll programmatically set every product in that category to draft/out of stock.

**e.g.** 'Category 1' has a purchase meta value of '20', after 20 unique users have purchased items belonging to Category 1, all items in that category will be hidden.

I can't find a great way to query orders containing items belonging to a specific category via WooCommerce, I'm not currently sure how to construct the wp database query and am slightly wary of having to query every purchase ever to determine category sales.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are hooking into the payment complete action already - would it then not perhaps make more sense, if you stored the number of already ordered items out of that category, _on_ the category as well? Add a second meta field for that, every time someone orders a product out of that category, increment that meta value by one … then you don’t have to go through _all_ orders every single time.

Comment: That's a good suggestion. Initially, I discounted that approach since technically customers can purchase multiple times from the same category, so I would probably need to query their previous purchases to make sure not to increment the counter in that case. I'm starting to think that might be a slightly nicer approach though as it avoids a fairly chunky database query joining multiple tables.